# how to update the rows while clicking on update button

Tags: javascript

How to update the current rows while clicking on update button using js: http://jsfiddle.net/8p1weyud/3504/`

```
/* update button */
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target)
    /* //console.log(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase, event.target.className, 'dummy', event.target.className.indexOf('updateCls'))
     once u click on the update button this will give the 23 of index  tht shud nt show -1 here updateCls  for reference  */
    if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button' && event.target.className.indexOf('updateCls') != -1) {
        /*set the attribute to target the modal box ,syntx:Element.setAttribute(name, value); */

        _updatebutton.setAttribute("data-target", '#formModel1')
        _updatebutton.setAttribute("data-toggle", 'modal')


        var row = _updatebutton.parentNode.parentNode;

        document.getElementById("firstName1").value = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("lastName1").value = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("email1").value = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("password1").value = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("phoneNumber1").value = row.cells[4].innerHTML;

    }
})
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what your are trying to do

Comment: i have a one button if i click on that button will get popup model box if i submit that that will add the rows, and that row contain update and delete button(dynamically created) if i click on update button it will fetch the current rows value but i trying give submit it will not update too the same row i need to update the row after submit the update button